# SparkViewEngine does it work with asp.net mvc Vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

I am trying to use new spark view engine .  i have done all necessery configuration as mentioned 
[here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Installing-the-Spark-View-Engine-into-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Preview-2.aspx)

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Installing-the-Spark-View-Engine-into-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Preview-2.aspx

and Have below Erorr message on run time..what am i missing?

AS in understand Spark view engine uses system.web 2.0  and vs2010 mvc project uses system.web 4.0... do we need to make any changes?

Dynamic view compilation failed. error

Spark.Compiler.CompilerException: Dynamic view compilation failed.
(0,0): error CS1668: Warning as Error: Invalid search path 'c:\open road\INGRES\LIB' specified in 'LIB environment variable' -- 'The system cannot find the path specified. '
ocating source for 'c:\Code\Spark\src\Spark.Web.Mvc\SparkViewFactory.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {1 1c 29 59 6f 9a 26 37 1b 96 c0 fb 1d 1a 34 11}

The file 'c:\Code\Spark\src\Spark.Web.Mvc\SparkViewFactory.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\Code\Spark\src\Spark.Web.Mvc\SparkViewFactory.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\Code\Spark\src\Spark.Web.Mvc\SparkViewFactory.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\Code\Spark\src\Spark.Web.Mvc\SparkViewFactory.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Code\Spark\src\Spark.Web.Mvc\SparkViewFactory.cs'.

Comment: I've personally only gotten Spark working in v4.0 once and I can't remember everything I had to do. (It was a side project and I lost the code.) I think you have to rebuild it from the source code. There's a string "v3.5" somewhere in there that has to be changed to "v4.0" if I recall correctly.

Comment: If you look on Google there's a message board posting somewhere with some of the steps listed.

Comment: I looked into Spark ssource Code and I have Error on below line

Comment: In Batchcompiler.cs file on below line
compilerResults = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(compilerParameters, 
codeFiles.ToArray());
where - 
compilerParameters.OutputAssembly = 
C:\\WINNT\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\a047bef1\\8fdc5bb242294874a7b50e8fca57432c.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark now works with .Net 4.0 for dynamic view compilation and the solution also opens in VS2010 from the master branch. You can either download the source and compile the latest binaries, or you can get the latest binaries using NuGet in VS2010.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Downloaded spark using Nuget and It works. It's strange earlier i have added same reference in my project to make it work. Seems binaries has been changed

Answer (score 0):

You might want to grab the solution provided [here](http://davidovitz.blogspot.com/2010/04/sample-mvc-2-aspnet-application-based.html).  Although I haven't tried it, it looks like someone got a solution working and shared it with the world.

Answer (score 0):

Try these instructions instead - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2009/12/21/video-spark-view-engine-part-1.aspx

Comment: i have tried these  instruction  atleast 10 times..with error. Have you personally tried to use it with V4 ?